# rspec-rails doesn't load app custom folder

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, ruby-2.0

don't know if it's even supported by rspec-rails.
I've created a folder inside app one, I want rpsec to load up that files without having to require each file of this folder in order to execute the tests.

Am I missing anything ?
Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rspec-rails` by default uses the standard Rails autoload instructions. Rails, by default, autoloads every folder inside the /app folder.

This means, if you create a folder inside `/app`, for example `app/workers`, then it will be added to the `LOAD_PATH`.

However, any folder inside the main app (e.g. /workers) or even the lib folder (`/lib/workers`) will not be automatically added to the `LOAD_PATH`.

In order to do that, you need to modify the `application.rb` file.

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

In any case, I would suggest to not create folders in the main path with Ruby libraries. Use either `/lib` or `/app`.

`rspec-rails` will follow the same autoload rules.